# Backbone JS central model where all views can use

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I am new to backbone js and require js.

I use requirejS to organize my backbone code into modules. I don't know if this has any importance to what I want though. I want to have a central model where all my views will have access to. They should be able to get and set values. I don't want to use it as each view model though. I need to keep in memory search options, user status (logged in/out) etc.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Maybe the answer is here?

[Share resources across different amd modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842223/share-resources-across-different-amd-modules)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With requirejs, I would create a module that defines a singleton model, let's say *app/settings.js*

```
define(['backbone'], function (Backbone) {
    var Settings = Backbone.Model.extend({
    });

    return new Settings();
});
```

and pull it in my other modules, for example

```
define(['backbone', 'app/settings'], function (Backbone, settings) {
    settings.set("pref", "my pref");
});
```

Subsequent calls to *app/settings.js* will return the same object.

Comment: So actually with requireJS we don't need namespaces?

Comment: @chchrist require.js modules act as namespaces of a sort, protecting the global from pollution and providing a hook for future references. With that in mind, yes, I think namespaces aren't needed with require.

Answer (score 4):

If I've understood well what you want I'll say you don't need anything special to having one `Model` in several `Views`, just do it:

```
// code simplified and no tested
App.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({});
App.View  = Backbone.View.extend({});

var myModel = new App.Model();
var viewOne = new App.View({ model: myModel });
var viewTwo = new App.View({ model: myModel });
```

### Updated after comment explanation

You can pass custom parameter to the `View.initialize`:

```
// code simplified and no tested
App.Model       = Backbone.Model.extend({});
App.CommonModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

App.View = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function( opts ){
    this.commonModel = opts.commonModel;
  }
});

var myModelOne    = new App.Model();
var myModelTwo    = new App.Model();
var myCommonModel = new App.CommonModel();

var viewOne = new App.View({ model: myModelOne, commonModel: myCommonModel });
var viewTwo = new App.View({ model: myModelTwo, commonModel: myCommonModel });
```

Comment: Each view has its own model so I can't use the App.Model as the view's model.