# Backbone and RequireJS shared collections not persistent

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I have a backbone + requireJS app where I use a AMD module called Globals to store some collections in a Global namespace. This is set up like so:

**globals.js**

```
define([
  'config',
  'underscore'
], function(config) {

  var globals = {
    collections : {}
  };

  _.extend(globals, config);

  return globals;

});
```

**myview.js**

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',

  'globals',

  'collections/MyCollection',

  'views/myOtherView',
], function($, _, Backbone, Globals, MyCollection, MyOtherView) {
     Globals.collections.myCollection = new MyCollection([]);

     console.log(Globals.collections);

     _.each(Globals.collection.models, function(myModel){
         var myOtherView = new MyOtherView({ model : myModel });
     });
});
```

**myOtherView.js**

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',

  'globals',

  'collections/MyCollection',
], function($, _, Backbone, Globals, MyCollection) {

    var MyOtherView = Backbone.View.extend({
      initialize : function(options){
        console.log(Globals.collections);
      }
    });
});
```

My question is why is my Globals.collections an empty object in the myOtherView.js object even though it's getting set in myView.js. 
The result of the console.log's is:

`Object { myCollection: d }`

`Object {}`

I simplified the above code but the case remains unchanged, for some reason the global objects properties don't stay persistent across the modules.

Any tips on why this happens?
(*I feel it has something to do with the _.each method?*)

Note: I have read these articles but although it does clear up on how to setup something like this it doesn't clearify why my collections object is empty

- [Backbone shared collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275790/backbone-shared-collections)

Comment: You should post some real code that shows the problem. This code would not work for other reasons. Your view modules don't return anything, and myview module iterates over an empty collection.

Comment: You're right, I already found my problem. It had to do with the fact I updated backbone with the non AMD version. stupid. Any way to delete this question?

Comment: Rather reply to your own question, explaining what you did wrong and how you corrected it, then you can accept your own answer as the solution and it will let others know how you fixed it.