# Set lodash / underscore template settings globally using require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, underscore.js

Is there a way to set the `templateSettings` for [lodash](http://lodash.com) when using [RequireJS](http://www.requirejs.org)?

Right now in my main startup I have,

```
  require(['lodash', 'question/view'], function(_, QuestionView) {
    var questionView;
    _.templateSettings = {
      interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
      evaluate: /\{\%(.+?)\%\}/g
    };
    questionView = new QuestionView();
    return questionView.render();
  });
```

but it doesn't seem to want to set the `templateSettings` globally because when I use `_.template(...)` in a module it wants to use the default `templateSettings`. The problem is that I don't want to change this setting in every module that uses `_.template(...)`.

Comment: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842223/share-resources-across-different-amd-modules) has an answer that is a viable solution to this situation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on @Tyson Phalp suggestion, that means [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842223/share-resources-across-different-amd-modules). 
 
I adapted it to your question and I tested it using RequireJS 2.1.2 and [SHIM configuration](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim).
This is the `main.js` file, that is where the requireJS config is:

```
require.config({
/*  The shim config allows us to configure dependencies for
    scripts that do not call define() to register a module */

    shim: {
      underscoreBase: {
        exports: '_'
      },
      underscore: {
        deps: ['underscoreBase'],
        exports: '_'
      }

    },
    paths: {
      underscoreBase: '../lib/underscore-min',
      underscore: '../lib/underscoreTplSettings',
    }
});

require(['app'],function(app){
  app.start();
});
```

Then you should create the `underscoreTplSettings.js` file with your templateSettings like so:

```
define(['underscoreBase'], function(_) {
    _.templateSettings = {
        evaluate:    /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
        interpolate: /\{\{=(.+?)\}\}/g,
        escape: /\{\{-(.+?)\}\}/g
    };
    return _;
});
```

So your module `underscore` will contain the underscore library and your template settings.
From your application modules just require the `underscore` module, in this way:

```
define(['underscore','otherModule1', 'otherModule2'], 
   function( _, module1, module2,) { 
      //Your code in here
   }
);
```

The only doubt I have is that I'm exporting the same symbol `_` two times, even tough this work I'm not sure if this is considered a good practice.

=========================

**ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION:**
This also works fine and I guess it's a little bit more clean avoiding to create and requiring an extra module as the solution above. I've changed the 'export' in the Shim configuration using an initialization function. For further understanding see the [Shim config reference](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim).

```
//shim config in main.js file
shim: {     
  underscore: {
      exports: '_',
      init: function () {
        this._.templateSettings = {
          evaluate:/\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
          interpolate:/\{\{=(.+?)\}\}/g,
          escape:/\{\{-(.+?)\}\}/g
        };
        return _; //this is what will be actually exported! 
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: but couldn't you just change what `underscoreBase` exports? I really like this solution though. Nice and clean with a very minor wrapper.

Comment: You are right, I added an alternative solution in the code above.

Comment: In case you're using Marionette with the requirejs-tpl plugin (https://github.com/ZeeAgency/requirejs-tpl) consider adding templateSettings = _.templateSettings || { ... }; to line 26 of tpl.js ... This prevents the boogery override of this useful solution above in RequireJS environments.

Comment: Should the assigned regexes for evaluate and interpolate in the above ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION be reversed? i.e. evaluate should have '='?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your **_** variable with template settings as function argument or as property in global object (**window** for browsers or **proccess** for nodejs).

```
_.templateSettings = {
      interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
      evaluate: /\{\%(.+?)\%\}/g
};
questionView = new QuestionView(_);
```

Or

```
_.templateSettings = {
      interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
      evaluate: /\{\%(.+?)\%\}/g
};
window._ = _
```

First option is better.

Comment: but then don't I have to keep passing it down all the way to the actual view thats going to use it? because I have a View containing a Collection, each element in the Collection has its own View and the single views of the collection elements are what is actually rendering templates.

Comment: Actualy you should, but if you can access other object from your view, you can "attach" _ to that object. You can set _ to prototype of your sigle view object, so you will define it once, not for every object: `collectionElementViewObject.constructor.prototype._ = _;` or `collectionElementView.prototype._ = _;`

Alternative is either to use global variable or singleton registry-like storage. But it's considired bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that if you're using underscore >=1.6.0 or lodash-amd the solution is pretty simple:

"main.js" configuration file

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: './', // Your base URL
  paths: {
    // Path to a module you create that will require the underscore module.
    // You cannot use the "underscore" name since underscore.js registers "underscore" as its module name.
    // That's why I use "_".
    _: 'underscore',

   // Path to underscore module 
   underscore: '../../bower_components/underscore/underscore',
  }
});
```

Your "_.js" file:

```
define(['underscore'], function(_) {

  // Here you can manipulate/customize underscore.js to your taste.
  // For example: I usually add the "variable" setting for templates
  // here so that it's applied to all templates automatically.

  // Add "variable" property so templates are able to render faster!
  // @see http://underscorejs.org/#template
  _.templateSettings.variable = 'data';

  return _;
});
```

A module file. It requires our "_" module which requires "underscore" and patches it.

```
define(['_'], function(_){
  // You can see the "variable" property is there
  console.log(_.templateSettings);   
});
```