# underscore template function override to inject HTML globally

Tags: javascript, html, underscore.js, lodash, underscore.js-templating

I tried with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057330/set-lodash-underscore-template-settings-globally-using-require-js) to override template function globally using require function and it works well for templateSetting.

I tried to extend/override the `_.template` function to wrap div using below code. But getting with plain template not parsed template like this `<%= title %>`

```
    define(['underscoreBase'], function(_) {
    _.template = function(str){
        return "<div class='test'>"+str+"</div>";
    };
    return _;
});
```

How do we acheive adding/wrap some HTML tag with _.template string content? Please advise.

Comment: Extending and overriding are completely different things. What exactly do you need?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos I wanted to override the _.template string to wrap with HTML

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a reference to the original `template` function:

```
define(['underscoreBase'], function(_) {
    var oldTemplate = _.template;
    _.template = function(str){
        return oldTemplate("<div class='test'>"+str+"</div>");
    };
    return _;
});
```

Comment: I tried,but got something like this
 function (obj){obj||(obj={});var __t,__p='',__e=_.escape,__j=Array.prototype.join;function print(){__p+=__j.call(arguments,'')}with(obj){__p+='
\r\n '; if (showRootHeader) { ; __p+='\r\n
'+((__t=( title ))==null?'':__t)+'
\r\n '; } ; __p+='\r\n

Comment: I tried already,now Uncaught ReferenceError: title is not defined :(

Comment: even i checked  like _.template = function(str){
        return str;
    }; returns same function code

Comment: There is no `title` in the code. This might be something else.

Comment: template str will have <%= title %>

Comment: So you need to call it like `_.template(' <%= title %>')({title: 'This is a title'})`.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented it like

```
var oldTemplate = _.template;
    function template(str, data) {
        return oldTemplate(
            "<div class='test'>"+str+"</div>",
            data
        );
    }
_.mixin({ template:template });
return _;
```